# Can an interface be implemented using static methods?

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-xe2

The following does not compile, but is something like it possible?

```
  IDefaultHelp = interface
  ['{6997FC42-7481-4CDA-940A-0351071266C7}']
    function GetTemplate: TXMLDocument;

  end;

  TDefaultHelp = class(TInterfacedObject, INodeHelp)
    class function GetTemplate: TXMLDocument; static;  <<-- error
  end;
```

I don't want to have to instantiate the implementing object.

**Is there a way to implement the interface without having to `Create` an actual class?**

Comment: If there is no instance, who's going to keep track of the reference count?

Comment: Of course, you probably don't want reference counting. So, if you are looking for an interface of static methods, take a look at how default comparer interfaces are implemented in the generics units. With records of function pointers laid out in vtable order.

Comment: Yes this is possible for non-refcounting interfaces; you still need an instance (there is no interface without an instance) but you can declare the instance as a constant so you need not create an instance at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that I don't really see the need to avoid instantiating an instance. Now, you cannot use static class methods to implement an interface. You can implement an interface by delegating to static class methods, if you so wish.

> I don't want to have to instantiate the implementing object.

So, taking your question as a desire to implement interfaces without the need to instantiate objects, you can use a constant vtable, implemented in the fashion of the comparer interfaces from the `Generics.Defaults` unit.

For example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Xml.XMLDoc;

type
  IDefaultHelp = interface
    ['{6997FC42-7481-4CDA-940A-0351071266C7}']
    function GetTemplate: IXMLDocument;
  end;

function GetDefaultHelp: IDefaultHelp;

implementation

function NopAddref(inst: Pointer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := -1;
end;

function NopRelease(inst: Pointer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := -1;
end;

function NopQueryInterface(inst: Pointer; const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; 
  stdcall;
begin
  Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function GetTemplate(inst: Pointer): IXMLDocument;
begin
  Result := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
end;

const
  DefaultHelp_Vtable: array[0..3] of Pointer =
  (
    @NopQueryInterface,
    @NopAddref,
    @NopRelease,
    @GetTemplate
  );
  DefaultHelp_Instance: Pointer = @DefaultHelp_Vtable;

function GetDefaultHelp: IDefaultHelp;
begin
  Result := IDefaultHelp(@DefaultHelp_Instance);
end;

end.
```

Comment: @user246408, it works just fine in System.Generics, why would it not work here?

Comment: means that System.Generics have no bug like the one above ;)

Comment: @user246408 It works when I run it. Why do you think it is wrong? Please do let us know rather than being so cryptic. If there's a problem then clearly I want to understand it.

Comment: Creates XML document? I don't believe you.

Comment: @user246408 I copied the code from Johan's answer and did not look at what `GetTemplate` actually does. I've never created an XML document in my life. What is wrong? OK, it's the life time management isn't it. If you pass `nil` to the constructor of `TXMLDocument`, the new object has lifetime managed by interface references. Try that edit. Is that what you mean.

Comment: the first mandatory parameter of any interface method is a pointer to an instance. An interface method just cannot be called without having this pointer. Though on the second thought your code will probably work with register calling convention still your `GetTemplate` is a bug - it should have `Inst: Pointer` parameter.